# Inserting System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting chart contorl into Word document

Tags: c#, charts, ms-word

Is it possible to insert System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting control into ms word document via Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Alternative solution is to save the chart as image and insert, but the image looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to insert "naked" .NET controls into a Word document - Word simply does not know how to handle them.

Using VSTO it's possible, since VSTO "wraps" the controls into a COM ActiveX control that Word is able to handle. That's something developers can do, themselves, but requires a lot of work. There are discussions on the topic in the VSTO forum on MSDN, for example

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1997b2c1-9806-4334-b99f-77f3333f8189/activex-control-development-for-ms-word?forum=vsto
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bc044717-9a83-4a66-992e-0c0664de9928/word-addin-and-winform-control?forum=vsto